# How to query exact range of rows in Impala?

Tags: impala

I want to get a result set of rows from 1000 to 2000 from an ordered query.

In Oracle I would use condition "rownum >= 1000 and rownum <= 2000"

Is there some way to do same thing using Impala?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to do it by using: 
"ORDER BY field_id
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000"

Comment: What if you don't want to order by a field? Is there some `rownum` we can order by to fulfill the syntax requirement for offset? In which case, why not just use `rownum between 1000 and 2000`...